# Gdal not working with Oracle Spatial's synonyms

Tags: gdal, ogr2ogr, oracle-dbms

I managed to get the OCI driver to work on both oracle table and views but I can't get it to work with synonyms.

Is this a limitation or am I doing something wrong?

Here's a sample of the command I'm using:

```
"C:\Program Files\GDAL\ogr2ogr.exe" -f "ESRI Shapefile" "test_shape.shp" "OCI:<schema>/<password>@(DESCRIPTION = (ADDRESS_LIST = (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1521)))(CONNECT_DATA = (SID =orcl))):MY_LOCAL_SYNONYM
```

I get the following error:

> ERROR 1: ORA-04043: object "MY_LOCAL_SYNONYM" does not exist

If I log into SQL Developer with the same schema/password and try to perform a select it works perfectly.

```
SELECT * FROM MY_LOCAL_SYNONYM;

SELECT * FROM <schema>.MY_LOCAL_SYNONYM;
```

Comment: What if you connect without the layer name and use `-sql "select * from my_local_synonym"`? The OCI driver probably wants to read some metadata from ALL_SDO_GEOMETRY_METADATA and you may need to insert a row for your synonym.

Comment: The synonym is listed in the USER_SDO_GEOM_METADATA. I have tried the -sql query as well (with and without schema prefix) without success.

Comment: Then it may be that synonyms are not supported.  Adding `--debug on` into your command prints some information about the SQL queries.

Comment: It does add some additional info but nothing that's too revealing. The most interesting part is that it after the object not existing error it appears to successfully connect?

    GDAL: GDALOpen(OCI:<schema>/<schema>@(DESCRIPTION = (ADDRESS_LIST = (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1521)))(CONNECT_DATA = (SID=orcl))):MY_LOCAL_SYNONYM, this=0000000001C39CC0) succeeds as OCI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Synonyms are just simply not supported by the OCI driver. Then again, hardly any GIS tool understands anything but straight tables. A few understand views. Very few (I don't know of any) understands synonyms.

In the case of GDAL, the OCI driver looks for a table or a view by the name you give, i.e. it searches for a table with that name in the USER_TABLES dictionary view, does not find any, then searches for a view in USER_VIEWS, and again does no find any.

Adding support for synonyms to the OCI driver is probably doable. You need to open a ticket for that at https://trac.osgeo.org/gdal